# Time-splitting data for cox regression affects cox.zph() proportional hazards check

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival

I'm doing a cox regression in R using `survival::coxph()` and the `Greg::timesplitter()` function to split up my data by time.  The impression I got from the documentation is that time-splitting should, in itself, make little to no difference to the regression results.  (Note that I'm not trying to model any time-dependent covariates or coefficients at this point, simply splitting the data by time).

This seems to be true for the main results of the regression itself (the coefficients output by `coxph()`).  However splitting sometimes (though not always) seems to make a large difference to the output of `cox.zph()`, the test of the proportional hazards assumption.  Is this expected and how should I interpret the results?

**Edit**: The behaviour also seems extremely sensitive to the data.  If I change the example below by cutting down the data to `fake_data[1:551,]` after creating it, I get roughly identical outputs from `cox.zph()` for the regular and split models.  But I get very different outputs if I cut the data down to `fake_data[1:550,]`.

Code reproducing the phenomenon:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)
library(Greg)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(56891)

fake_data <- tibble("id" = c(1:5000))

n <- nrow(fake_data)

fake_data$gender <- if_else(runif(n) > 0.5, "M", "F")
fake_data$event_status <- if_else(runif(n) > 0.3, 1, 0)
fake_data$time_to_event <- round(500*runif(n),3)

regular_model <- coxph(Surv(time_to_event, event_status == 1) ~ gender,
                       data = fake_data,
                       x = TRUE, y = TRUE)
`
spl_data <-
  fake_data %>% 
  timeSplitter(by = 5,
               event_var = "event_status",
               event_start_status = 0,
               time_var = "time_to_event")

split_model <- coxph(Surv(Start_time, Stop_time, event_status) ~gender,
                                     data = spl_data,
                                     x = TRUE, y = TRUE)

regular_model
split_model

cox.zph(regular_model)
cox.zph(split_model)
```